# Problem with microSD SPI mode in AVR

Tags: avr

I'm trying to read a microSD block. But I don't know why it doesn't work.

I do:

```
CS_UP;
for(uint8_t i = 0; i <14; i++){ /* Send 74+ clocks */
    spi_tranceiver(0xff);
}
_delay_ms(1); /* Wait 1 ms */

//CS_UP;

/* Initizalize microSD */
put_string("Go to idle state\n");
while (Reset_Card() != 0x01) // Go to idle state
    ;

put_string("Send IF COND\n");
while (Send_CMD8() != 0x01) // SEND IF COND
    ;

put_string("Send ACMD41 and CMD55\n");
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++)
    while (Send_CMD55() && Send_ACMD41())
        ;

setBlockLen(); // Set block read in 512 bytes
CS_DOWN;
put_string("\nConfigure finished correctly\n");
```

And then I just call:

```
readSingleBlock(0x00, &buf)
```

readSingleBlock is defined as follows:

```
uint8_t readSingleBlock(uint32_t block_address, unsigned char *buf)
{
    int i;

    block_address = block_address << 9;

    CS_UP;
    while (0x00 != sdsc_command(READ_SINGLE_BLOCK, block_address))
        ;

    while (0xfe != spi_rx ())
        ;

    for (i = 0; i < 512; i ++ ){
        //buf [ i ] = spi_rx();
        put_int(spi_rx());
        put_string("\n");
    }
    spi_rx();
    spi_rx();
    CS_DOWN;

    //for (i = 0; i<512; i++) put_int(buf[i]);
```

The problem is that the printout is:

0 0 0 ..(zeros).. 128 255 255 255 12 255 255 255 0 8 0 0 0 72 59 ..(zeros).. 85 170

Did somebody encounter this problem?

Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: Please add, which printout you were expecting. Also please post, how many zeroes are printed out at the respective parts of the output. This makes it easier to trace down the problem.

Comment: And now we're equating "AVR" with "Arduino"? What the hell?

Comment: I use Arduino Mega Board. But I don't use Arduino Language programming.

Answer (score 1):

I formated the SD card, and then work correctly

Thanks!